# How do I add a nested conditional within an echo - to use a default image if there isn't one in the post?

Tags: images, conditional-tags, conditional-content, customization

I'm trying to add a conditional that will display a default image if the "image" field isn't populated... here's what I'm trying to work with:

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'meta_query' => array( 
      array(
         'key' => 'is_featured', 
         'value' => '1',
         'compare' => '!=', // NOT Featured
      )
   )
);

$second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
   while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); 

   $attachment_id = get_field('image');
   $size = "customfeatins"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
   $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );

        echo '<article>

            <img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() .'" width="136" height="90" />
            <h3>' . get_the_title() .'</h3>
            <p class="date">' . get_the_date() .'</p>

        </article>
        ';

   endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I've tried this but it breaks the page:

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'meta_query' => array( 
      array(
         'key' => 'is_featured', 
         'value' => '1',
         'compare' => '!=', // NOT Featured
      )
   )
);

$second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
   while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); 

  if( get_field('image') ){

    $attachment_id = get_field('image');
    $size = "customfeatins"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );

    } else {

    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 'http://placehold.it/136x90' );

    }       

    endif;

        echo '<article>

            <img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() .'" width="136" height="90" />
            <h3>' . get_the_title() .'</h3>
            <p class="date">' . get_the_date() .'</p>

        </article>
        ';

   endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working - thanks everyone for the feedback, with that I was able to rethink things a little and figure out a solution that does just what I wanted it to :)

Here it is (also filtering through tags to get related posts):

```
<?php
                    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                        $tag_ids = array();
                        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;

                        $args = array(
                            'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                            'posts_per_page' => 3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
                            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                    );  

                    $second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
                        echo '<div class="title fs-60 salmon">Related Posts</div>';
                        while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post();

                        $titlechars = 45; // Character Limit
                        $posttitle = get_the_title();
                        $modtitle = substr($posttitle, 0, $titlechars);

                        $contentchars = 120; // Character Limit
                        $postcontent = get_the_excerpt();
                        $modcontent = substr($postcontent, 0, $contentchars);

                    echo '<article>';

                ?>

                <?php

                    if( get_field('image') ):

                        $attachment_id = get_field('image');
                        $size = 'customfeatins'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );

                    echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() .'" width="136" height="90" />';

                ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/136x90" alt="image" />

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php

                    echo '
                        <h3 class="purple">' . $modtitle .'</h3>
                        <p class="date">' . get_the_date() .'</p>
                        <p>' . $modcontent . '&hellip; <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">More &rsaquo;</a></p>

                        </article>';

                ?>
                <?php 
                    endwhile;
                    endif;
                    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

This uses the placeholder image (set as placehold.it for now) if the post doesn't have an image in the custom image field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this won't work:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 'http://placehold.it/136x90' );
```

As [**`wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id )`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) requires an *attachment ID*, as an *integer*, to be passed as `$id`.

If you have a fallback default image in the Theme, you can call it like so:

```
$image = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/fallback.png';
```

Or, if you want the user to select an image from the media library to use, you'll need to query that image by `$id`. How you do that will depend on how you store the user's selection.

### Edit

> the fall back is almost working, however it's only outputting the first character in the source, e.g.: `src="/"`

That's because in one case, you're putting an *array* inside of `$image`, and in the fallback, you're putting a *string* inside of `$image`. But in your output, you reference `$image[0]`, which implies that `$image` is an array.

I would recommend passing `$image[0]` into a separate variable, perhaps `$image_src`. Then, you can reference `$image_src` in the fallback case, and then also *output* `$image_src`.

For **example**:

```
if( get_field('image') ){
    // stuff
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
    // ADD THIS
    $image_src = $image[0];
} else {
    // USE $image_src HERE AS WELL
    $image_src = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/fallback.png';
}
// more stuff
// ...skipping ahead
// ...

// USE $image_src HERE AS WELL
<img src="' . $image_src . '" alt="' . get_the_title() .'" width="136" height="90" />
```

Comment: Chip - the fall back is almost working, however it's only outputting the first character in the source, e.g.: `src="/"`

Comment: See updated answer, with explanation and example code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$second_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $second_query->have_posts() ):
   while( $second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); 

    $attachment_id = get_field('image');
    $size = "customfeatins"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $my_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );


    if (!my_image !== ''){ 

      $image = $my_image[0];

    } else {

      $image = 'http://domain/image_source/your_image.jpg';

    }       

    endif;

        echo '<article>

            <img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . get_the_title() .'" width="136" height="90" />
            <h3>' . get_the_title() .'</h3>
            <p class="date">' . get_the_date() .'</p>

        </article>
        ';

   endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, this didn't work though, not sure why but it broke the page...